# What approaches are available to reduce the time needed for a large site scrape?

Tags: java, web-scraping, web-crawler

I need to scrape a pretty big amount of data from a website. This website does not belong to me. The website is pretty fast.

To get the data I need to input some data, fire a POST request and then click all links of the differing result list.  For each link I need to parse the resulting page that appears when you click it. Right now I am simply using Selenium.

I estimated that I need around 13 hours to parse all what I want.

Performance is not really that important but I am afraid that 13 hours is a little too long and errors might arise from a program trying to perform 13 hours straight (some kind of freezes, interruptions or whatever and that all would add complexity to the whole thing).

Is there a Java framework that is suited better for what I am trying to achieve than Selenium? I am not sure if it's Selenium or the website that bottlenecks. I already multi-thread the application. But I think Selenium is not meant to be used for what I abuse it for, so maybe something else is faster?

So far I have only came across JSoup and it seems to be poorly suited for handling input.  I need to perform input as described in the question. The website I am using uses POST requests to load data, so I cannot simply to it by URL.

Comment: Jsoup is can parse HTML pages. It also can make POST requests or you can use another way to obtain the data (e.g. OkHttp) and use Jsoup to parse the response (it accepts InputStreams, Readers and whatnot)

Comment: And can i expect it to be faster than Selenium? Is there any statistic / experience? Maybe it can also determined from a technological viewpoint?
Say jsoup is faster for the parsing itself, is it also faster when it does POST-Requests?
The website i work on has excessive amounts of POST-Request form Data, it will take a lot of effort to implement by hand. Can i expect the result to be a lot faster? What if i use, say HtmlUnit, to perform input for me. Will i then have any benefit compared to using Selenium?

Comment: I posted a comment, not an answer, because I just wanted to point out an error in your question. Generally, if you have network requests they are the slowest thing in your application. I doubt that just changing the framework would improve things much. Your best option is parallel requests. That said, selenium is designed for test automation, while jsoup is for scraping. I'd expect that jsoup may be better suited for your task.

Comment: I didn't downvote this question, but one reason others might have, is that it asks for opinion. Read the FAQ if you want to know why its considered off topic.

Comment: Wasn't directed towards you. I am afraid i have to heavily disagree that this falls under "opinion" though. It's absolutely not an opinion such as "what is the best car?". It really isnt at all. Everyone that considered the question for more than 5 seconds would know. I agree that it might look like an opinion question on the first look but as i said: Read the question for more than 5 seconds and you will realise that it is a technical. based question that i did research on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

I implemented the same logic with Jsoup and the time bench mark yielded the results for a fixed amount of data:

- Selenium: 2 minutes 46 seconds
- Jsoup: 16 seconds

Thus it seems that Selenium is much slower. I cannot give a technical reason why this is so. I can only make a guess and say that it is because of the rendering overhead.

Comment: Selenium uses Firefox by default, which will render web pages and execute JavaScript. This is much slower than JSoup, since the latter does not support JavaScript, nor does it render the page.

Answer (score 2):

How many HTTP requests do you estimate are required to do a full scrape of your target site? That you want to do 13 hours worth of constant scraping - and that you want it to complete faster - makes me wonder whether you're in danger of causing an unintentional denial of service attack against the target.

It is worth considering that, even if the site in question can ably handle the traffic you are sending to them, your crawler appearing frequently in their logs may put you at risk of IP blocking, and this risk presumably will increase if you are successful at making the process faster.

A better policy is to ensure you have a **maximum** scrape speed: if you don't have a couple of seconds delay between HTTP operations, add that in. You can subtract time for your own overheads, so if page parsing and rendering takes 0.5 sec on average, put a 1.5 second delay in, so as to meet your target delay time.

Of course, without any information about the kind of site you are scraping, where you are based, where the target is based and what you plan to do with the data, we are just guessing as to the legality and morality of your operation. It is possible that you should just not do it, usually based on copyright concerns. If there is an API for what you are doing, use that instead.

Bear in mind that the target site can block your operation (or sue you) at any time, and thus you need to consider how your enterprise would obtain the data another way if that happens.

Comment: I have about 8500 inputs, each is connected with an average of 31 requests. So that's around 263500 requests that are being made. But i only load the site with around 4 requests a second. From my understanding the website should be able to handle this quite easily. Infact the website belongs to some agency of the state. 
The risk of legality has been handled and someone else is taking it, that is not my beer.

Anyways, thanks for the answer, the delay is an interesting idea and i might even put some in.

Comment: Yes, I personally think 4 req/sec is too fast. The target will probably cope fine, but what if other people try to do the same thing? Public/state-funded agencies are more likely to share the data than private bodies though: could someone from your org approach the target and ask if this is OK? Furthermore, maybe you could set up an API with the data you scrape and offer that publicly (with permission) - in an age of open data, you'd be saving the publicly-funded target some work in exchange for stable permission to grab the data in the first place.

Comment: You bring up some interesting points there. However, infact the data was requested by our company and the request was rejected. I guess none of the hoster of the website wanted any additional work (querying their DB, packing and sending and also probably numerous "may i even do that and who do i ask??" issues). 

Your last point is an interesting idea, i might suggest that to the authorities. Data will be scraped in the future, too. 

But after all i think people of the site were simply too lazy and thus don't care if we get the data in another way, don't you think so too?

Comment: @Mercious: assuming it was the state organisation who rejected your request to obtain the data safety, it would be interesting to know why they rejected it. If it is just laziness or bureaucracy then that may be in your favour, since they may also not pay attention to high levels of traffic from your IP range. However, if they have copyright or other legal concerns, and they find you are scraping despite having been officially denied access to the data, they may choose to block you, and your project will be stuffed.

Comment: (`s/safety/safely/` of course)

Comment: There is always the possibility that they actually don't wan't it to be scraped, true. Luckily this is not my issue, however i will pick a few of your points and hand them in as suggestion to them for the future. I don't know if they had any discussion about it or not. 
I am indeed a little concerned that they will ban the IP. But as we speak i am scraping and close to being done. Luckily the page isn't that complex and i could develop the algorithm in only a few days. 
Anyways, thanks for your input, let's see what the future brings :)